# How to get Locations using the FusedLocationApi even if the phone goes sleep?

Tags: android, gps, android-service, alarmmanager, android-location

I have a service where I do all the work on getting the device location in order to send it over to my server.

In order to get the location I'm using Google's `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` API like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationIntentService.class);
mLocationPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(1500).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, request, mLocationPendingIntent);
```

The above works fine, excepts when the phone goes sleep, by means of the screen automatically going off or manually pushing the power button in order to do so.

So there's the problem, the gps stops getting location results even though the service is still up; not yet eaten by the system.

I thinking that the problem might be the actual gps which gets turned off by the system to save battery but I don't know how to set it not to stop sending me locations even though the phone is idle.

I thought on setting a repeating alarm on `AlarmManager` to callback to my `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` implementation but doing so would be very battery consuming and even unfeasible since it seems like the system is capping alarm intervals for that reason since Android  5.1.

Comment: did you try using a foreground service?

Comment: @tyczj Yes, actually the code snippet on my question runs inside a service. Then I ask FusedLocationApi for location changes and I get this changes on a separate IntentService. For the moment it seems to be working, but need much more tests.